# Navigating to a component in Communities

Tags: lightning, lightning-community, parameters

I have a simple parent child component. This is surfaced in the community, and for some reason, the parent component is not able to call the child component via the lightning:navigation service. I have below a small code excerpts. It is my understanding that the lightning:navigation is now supported in communities.

ParentComponent

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:isUrlAddressable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable">

    <lightning:navigation aura:id="navService" />
    <lightning:button  aura:id="mybtn" name="mybtn" variant="base" onclick="{!c.openChildComponent }" label="Open Child"/>


</aura:component>


openChildComponent : function (component, event, helper) {
                    component.find("navService").navigate({
                        "type": "standard__component",
                        "attributes": {
                            "componentName": "c__ChildComponent" },
                        "state": {} 
                    }, true); // replace = true      
            }
```

ChildComponent

```
<aura:component controller="myController" access="global" implements="lightning:isUrlAddressable,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes">

   <aura:attribute name="pageReference" type="Object" access="global" />

</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 0):

i found 2 issues with your code.

1. you should use   "[comm__namedPage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation_page_definitions.htm)" instead   "standard__component" for communities.
2. you need create one community page and  drag and drop your component into that page.

then use below code, it works for me.

```
    openChildComponent : function (component, event, helper) {
var navservice = component.find("navService");
var pageReference = {
         "type": "comm__namedPage",
                        "attributes": {
                            "pageName": "yourcommunitypage" },
                        "state": {"parameter1":'abc",
                                  "parameter2":'abc",} 
    };
     sessionStorage.setItem('localTransfer', JSON.stringify(pageReference.state));    
     
     
    navService.navigate(pageReference);
```

you can read parameters in child component init function

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
       
        var localStuff = sessionStorage.getItem('localTransfer');
    console.log("localStuff =>"+localStuff);
    if(localStuff){
        var state = JSON.parse(localStuff);
        console.log(state.parameter1);
        console.log(state.parameter2);
        
    }   
    },
```